# Do Spring MVC themes support different localizations?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, localization

I need to have theme support for a Spring MVC web app which includes css, images and text.

Currently all the text is in `<spring:message>` tags. Will I be able to supply different language.properties files for each theme and locale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at this some more - it seems to provide localized themes the easiest way is to have all messages in `spring:theme` tags. You then need only provide a theme properties file for each locale.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible please refer to example on [link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-themes-tutorial-example/)

Comment: That example uses the same messages.properties files for each theme, I want different ones for each theme

Comment: no i think it has 2 language (en,de) and 3 themes (default,black,blue). if you download source code under resources folder these are located.

Comment: I understand it has two languages - what I want is to supply a different language_en.properties file for each theme. The example you linked uses the same localized message file for each theme.

Comment: hmm.., then i think best way to do this is to extend ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource, and load properties file based on theme selected by user.